# Confusion about orthogonal matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

given an orthogonal transformation $T: \mathbb R^{n}\longrightarrow\mathbb R^{n}$. We also know that the representation matrix $A$ of $T$ is orthogonal if the $A^TA =I$ or the columns of A are an orthogonal basis for $ \mathbb R^{n} $. Is A only orthogonal if it's the matrix of T with respect to some ONB basis or any basis would work in this case?

Comment: Perhaps try it yourself, with a basis like $(\lambda E_1, E_2)$ of $\Bbb R^2$, where $(E_1, E_2)$ is the standard (o.n.) basis.

Comment: If you don't work with an ONB, the matrix does not represent an orthogonal transformation.

Answer (score 1):

If $T:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is orthogonal then $(Tx,Tx)=(x,x)$
for all $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$.
If $A\in \mathbb{R}^{nxn}$ represents $T$ $\textbf{with respect to an orthonormal basis}$ this becomes

$(Ax)^T(Ax)=x^TA^TAx=x^Tx$

for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$.
In particular

$(A^TA)_{ij}=e_i^TA^TAe_j=e_i^Te_j=\delta_{ij}$

where $\{e_i\}$ are the standard basis vectors. I.e. $A^TA=I$.

You don´t have this translation into a matrix equation if You don´t work with an orthonormal basis though as simple counterexamples show. Take the basis $\{\begin{pmatrix}2\\0\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\end{pmatrix}\}$
for $\mathbb{R}^2$ as suggested by Travis and consider a rotation by $\frac{\pi}{2}$ which is definitely orthogonal but its matrix with respect to this basis is

$\begin{pmatrix}0&-\frac{1}{2}\\2&0\end{pmatrix}$
and this is obviously not orthogonal.